# How to all same class instance with different URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

Twitter and facebook, among others, display the same page layout and then they fill it with specific information based on url information.

For example: twitter.com/*bob* will show the *profile* layout/page but with *bob* information.

Using a standard URL structure (*domain.com/controller/action*), how do I call the same controller with a different url each time?

Comment: "Using a standard mvc structure (domain.com/controller/action)" -> this is not a standard mvc structure.. not even a common way to structure urls. Used in a few frameworks but no way convention. Please add your specific code

Comment: There are many possibilities to implement this.

Comment: Which will be the most common one?

Comment: It depends but .htaccess is the thing you need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an additonal route
when you have

```
/{controller}/{action}
```

you can also add

```
/alias/{action}
```

you just need to pass it to the desired controller instead of the variable used in the default route

Answer (score 0):

You need three things.

1. A web server that allows for URL rewriting such as Apache with mod_rewrite or Nginx with a proxy setup.
2. A [Front Controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/)
3. A [router](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/) that will map the URLs

Front controllers are simple scrips where all of your requests get routed to. This will usually instantiate the router & other objects. The router is what takes care to instantiate the controller & pass it parameter from either the query string or the POST body or the URL.

You should look at [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) or [Aura](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router) for router implementation examples.